# Cypher MATCH query speed

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have Neo4j installed on a windows machine with 12 processors and 64GB ram.  I did not change any of the memory settings that Neo4j allows for.

My database has 3.8m nodes, 210,000 of which are labeled as Geotagged and a total of 650,000 relationships.  I am trying to run the following query and I am wondering if this is a really intensive query that will likely take quite a while.

Messages.csv is my relationship file.  The relationships have already been created, but as I could not figure out how to combine the relationship creation with the below Distance generation, I am loading and running through the relationship file twice.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 15000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/messages.csv" AS line
MATCH (a:Geotagged { username: line.sender }) - [r:MSGED] -> (b:Geotagged { username: line.recipient })
SET r.Distance = (2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat) - toFloat(a.statusLat))) + cos(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat))) * cos(radians(toFloat(a.statusLat))) * haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLon) - toFloat(a.statusLon))))));
```

The initial relationship generation takes about 3-5 minutes.  I let the above run for over an hour and it still was not complete.  I ran a similar algorithm (though it had a few more trig calls in it) on the same initial db and let it run for over 18 hours and still had not completed.

My question: Is this a very intensive query?  Am I not giving it enough time?  And more importantly, is there a way I can optimize this?

I tried adding "WHERE NOT HAS(r.Distance)" to exclude node pairs that the algorithm has already set the Distance on, though I am unsure if the MATCH is a one-time match or if it will MATCH for each line in the CSV file?

Any thoughts on this would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

One way that I would start to debug is to put a limit on it using `WITH`:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 15000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/messages.csv" AS line
WITH line LIMIT 100
MATCH (a:Geotagged { username: line.sender }) - [r:MSGED] -> (b:Geotagged { username: line.recipient })
SET r.Distance = (2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat) - toFloat(a.statusLat))) + cos(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat))) * cos(radians(toFloat(a.statusLat))) * haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLon) - toFloat(a.statusLon))))));
```

With that you can change the `LIMIT` number to see how the performance degrades as the limit increases.

Also, is the `username` property indexes for the `Geotagged` label?  If not it definitely should be, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Geotagged(username)
```

If it's unique and you want the database to enforce that:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (g:Geotagged) ASSERT g.username IS UNIQUE
```

Comment: Sorry, yes I have already constrained the username to be unique, though I was under the impression the CONSTRAINT automatically creates the index....?

Answer (score 2):

This is additional to  Brian's reply:

Your statement's query plan shows `EAGER`, to verify run

```
EXPLAIN explain LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/messages.csv" AS line
WITH line LIMIT 100
MATCH (a:Geotagged { username: line.sender }) - [r:MSGED] -> (b:Geotagged { username: line.recipient })
SET r.Distance = (2 * 6371 *asin(sqrt(haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat) - toFloat(a.statusLat))) + cos(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat))) * cos(radians(toFloat(a.statusLat))) * haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLon) - toFloat(a.statusLon))))));
```

[image: query plan with eager]

Eagerness in `LOAD CSV` is pretty bad, see the these blog posts why:

- http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/
- http://jexp.de/blog/2014/10/load-cvs-with-success/

Following Mark's suggested and replacing the `MATCH/SET` with a `MERGE ON MATCH SET` we can refactor that into:

```
explain LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/messages.csv" AS line
WITH line LIMIT 100
MATCH (a:Geotagged { username: line.sender }), (b:Geotagged { username: line.recipient })
MERGE (a)-[r:MSGED]->(b)
ON MATCH SET r.Distance = (2 * 6371 * asin(sqrt(haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat) - toFloat(a.statusLat))) + cos(radians(toFloat(b.statusLat))) * cos(radians(toFloat(a.statusLat))) * haversin(radians(toFloat(b.statusLon) - toFloat(a.statusLon))))));
```

And `eager` has vanished. [image: query plan without eager]

Comment: Stefan, thank you, I was unaware of the PROFILE capability or even of the issue with eager.    
I've since changed the query as you suggested and ran with limits of 10 and 100.  Both made 0 modifications (i.e. those lines did not represent messages sent from one geotagged user to another geotagged user).  10 lines took 11.5sec and 100 lines took 71 seconds.  The file has 3,712,112 lines, so extrapolating based on the 71sec/100 lines, that's roughly 30 days.  Is that surprising at all or is that normal?  
Just FYI, my original query ran 100 lines in 36 seconds (half that of the revised syntax).

Comment: that's way too slow. I guess you can gain a lot by switching over to Linux.

Comment: Hi Stefan, is the windows implementation really that unreliable?  I've also changed the pagecache with no change.  I also posted another question on this, but the index created by the unique constraint doesn't show up in shell when I run 'index --indexes', is that normal?

Comment: By far the most of the production installations I'm aware of are running on Linux. In Neo4j <=2.1.x, the filebuffer cache is off-heap on Linux and on-heap in Windows - that is one important difference. In 2.2 the filebuffer cache has been superseded with the page cache which is off heap independent of the OS. I also have the impression (without knowing the facts) that memory management is far better in Linux vs. Windows - but I don't want to start a flame war here.

Comment: You still have NodeByLabel scan stefan :)