# Neo4j Index created by constraint

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am still trying to resolve my speed issue (shown here: [Cypher MATCH query speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29521401/cypher-match-query-speed)).

One thing I noticed is that while I am importing the data with a unique constraint (proven by the below).

> neo4j-sh (?)$ create index on :Person(username);
>
> QueryExecutionKernelException: Label 'Person' and property 'username'
> have a unique constraint defined on them, so an index is already
> created that matches this.

When I try to view the indexes in shell, I get the following:

> neo4j-sh (?)$ index --indexes
> Node indexes:
>
> Relationship indexes:

Are autogenerated indexes not supposed to show up?  How can I verify that the unique constraint is in-fact indexing the username?

The main problem (as shown in the above link) is that the below simple query is taking 36 seconds (with an eager call) and twice that time when switched to a non-eager call.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 15000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:d:/messages.csv" AS line
MATCH (a:Geotagged { username: line.sender }) - [r:MSGED] -> (b:Geotagged { username: line.recipient })
RETURN NULL;
```

Note, this is excluding the SET call I was originally trying to use, I removed it and the MATCH alone is taking forever.

Additionally, I have also increased the pagecache to several times what I should need and saw no change.

**EDIT 1**
The nodes labeled with 'Geotagged' are ALSO labeled as 'Person'.  All nodes are 'Person', some just happen to also be 'Geotagged'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you used an uniqueness constrain with the Geotagged label as well as the Person label? I found that a uniqueness constrain on both labels increased speed greatly.

Comment: My import/upload process is to set the unique constraint on Person:username and then upload everything, all under the Person label.  In that same query, I have a series of CASE WHEN + FOREACH statements that examine that nodes properties and add a specific label to it.  You're suggesting I might need to constrain on each individual label?

Comment: Yes. I had a similar issue. I had only 3 choices for my secondary label, not sure how many you are adding. I found that adding the uniqueness constraint for each of the three secondary labels increased speeds exponentially.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `index` command for legacy indexes, **use `schema` to list schema indexes and constraints**.

Also if you match by `:Geotagged(username)` you have to have an index for that combination:

```
 create index on :Geotagged(username);
```

or match on `:Person(username)` instead.

Comment: Michael, thank you!  I was struggling with that.  Is there a way to create the index on already existing nodes?  It seems like the create index command simply adds the index and doesn't actually index the nodes.

Comment: I started a writeup, can you provide me some feedback if that would have helped you? http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?dropbox-14493611%2Fneo4j_indexes_match_and_merge.adoc

Comment: An schema index will always also index existing nodes with that label and property combination.

Comment: Hi Michael, i'd be happy to review it and provide feedback, but I couldn't access the document, I think the URL was incorrect?

Comment: I ran "create index on :Geotagged(username)" and it was done in less than a second, as if there were no nodes to index.  That should have indexed on all existing nodes?  I assume that would have taken a few minutes?